# Comparing GRASS v.Overlay/QGIS Intersect Speed intersecting line and polygon?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

Im currently trying to convert my scripts from ArcGIS to QGIS but one aspect that is extremely slow is trying to intersect a polygon with a line feature. I feel as though there must be a better way to accomplish trying to clip the voronoi polylines with the original polygon itself i.e. :

[image: Voronoi_Lines]

**by**

[image: Original Polygon]

These are some of the bench tests that i've done with these two layers.

**ArcGIS 10.1 Intersect**
2min 24sec

**Grass 7 v.Overlay** 
quit after ~1hour (~70% Selecting lines...) - Currently not supported in processing (Sextante)

**Grass 7 v.split + v.Overlay**
~2min + 45min

**QGIS 1.9**
quit after ~3hours

**ogr2ogr -clipsrc**
quit after > 1hour

**SAGA GIS Intersect Line-Polygon**
~15min -- acceptable but still 7x slower than ArcGIS and produces wrong results? The images below show SAGA GIS Intersect(with dangles removed) and same area with ArcGIS Intersect - Clearly SAGA did not intersect the line and polygon correctly as there should be no connection of the lines. These errors are scattered throughout the new output!!! In addition Line-Polygon does not retain the polygon intersect attributes to the line unlike the other methods mentioned above...

[image: SAGA GIS Intersect]

I have placed the **original dataset** in a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/BJEBN/Geometric-Analysis/tree/master/Examples) so hopefully others can make their own benchmarks and thereby provide suggestions?

I notice that ArcGIS Desktop splits (cracking) the featureclass so I do not know if that is another possibility to improve intersection speed within one of the opensource alternatives mentioned above?

***Note that the reason I mention QGIS here is that I have made some scripts within the processing toolbox (formally known as Sextante) and i'd like to remain in that environment if at all possible.

**System** - Intel Core i7-2760QM CPU @2.40GHz and 8GB ram

Comment: you should try a benchmark using OGR directly: http://darrencope.com/2011/03/31/clipping-large-shapefiles-using-ogr/ - you can use that in the Processing toolbox as well.

Comment: How about the SAGA function from the toolbox? They seem to be very fast and reliable. The default intersect and other default tools in QGIS are a real pain in the a..

Comment: @BJEBN: Can you put the data set online so that we can benchmark ourselves?

Comment: @Darren/@Bernd/@markusN see updated post

Comment: @BJEBN; unfortunately I don't have time right now to try a benchmark, but another thought may be to try the 64bit version of QGIS available as an experimental build from http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (assuming you're on a 64bit machine) and see if the processing time is any faster. Otherwise, you could add the GRASS v.split and v.overlay to the Processing toolbox - not that hard to do following the instructions here: http://fossies.org/linux/misc/qgis-2.0.1.tar.gz:a/qgis-2.0.1/python/plugins/processing/grass/grass.txt

Comment: @DarrenCope Thanks for that I added the functionality that I wanted from GRASS...

Comment: Great! You may want to submit your description files to @Victor Olaya (Sextante/Processing developer) and he will roll it into the release so others can benefit! – Darren Cope 29 mins ago

Comment: A previous "clipping contest": http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.ru/2012/11/the-great-geometry-clipping-contest.html

Comment: I have worked on the same problem. I took some (approx. 100) polygons, some of which are rather very complex (some 100K vertices and many hundreds holes etc). The polygons are actually a vectorized raster layer (compares to the second image). I intersected a fishnet polygon layer with it. - In ArcGIS this intersection took about 30 seconds. - In PostGIS it took about 1 hour!! - same in QGis (probably the same algorithm) It seems like the ArcGIS algorithm is much better here, when it comes to complex geometries. On the contrary, when I then took the intersection result (i.e. the fishnetted mega

Comment: I think this could be a very useful question, because I think what you are asking is "Can QGIS clip faster than it currently does?" and you are using the speed of comparable operations to try and show why you think it is not fast enough.  Would you be able to revise your question to try and make it clearer, please?

Answer (score 1):

What I did to speed up this process was to load SHP files in PostgreSQL and do clipping there. Not a perfect solution but faster for me since I quite powerful server behind it.  And yes, this operations are slow.